# @MockBean returns null during controller testing with @RolesAllowed annotation

Tags: mockito, spring-boot-test

I have a set of working Controller Junit/Mockito tests which started failing after making necessary changes for authorization. As part of Authorization,I added @RolesAllowed annotation for controller methods (end points) and @WithMockUser to ControllerTests. All the tests started failing as the service @MockBean used in the controllerTest is null.

Below is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.numpyninja.lms.services.ProgramServices.createAndSaveProgram(com.numpyninja.lms.dto.ProgramDTO)" because "this.programServices" is null
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at com.numpyninja.lms.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at com.numpyninja.lms.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:199)
    at com.numpyninja.lms.controller.ProgramControllerTest.testCreateProgram(ProgramControllerTest.java:88)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.numpyninja.lms.services.ProgramServices.createAndSaveProgram(com.numpyninja.lms.dto.ProgramDTO)" because "this.programServices" is null
    at com.numpyninja.lms.controller.ProgramController.createAndSaveProgram(ProgramController.java:66)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

The strange thing is that the issue occurs for few controllers and it doesn't occur for others. The stack trace for the controller where similar change is made and tests are passing is below. MethodProxy invoke is run here which is not the case in former. Not sure why.

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 40 in AssignmentController))   
    AssignmentController.createAssignment(AssignmentDto) line: 40   
    AssignmentController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$684ae619.invoke(int, Object, Object[]) line: not available    
    MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 218  
    CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 779 
    CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 163 
    CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 750 
    MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 61 
    CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 186 
    CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed() line: 750 
    CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 692  
    AssignmentController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6ce4fe65.createAssignment(AssignmentDto) line: not available   
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 77  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 568  
    ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).doInvoke(Object...) line: 205 
    ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(InvocableHandlerMethod).invokeForRequest(NativeWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 150    
    ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletWebRequest, ModelAndViewContainer, Object...) line: 117    
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 895  
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HandlerMethod) line: 808   
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter).handle(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Object) line: 87 
    TestDispatcherServlet(DispatcherServlet).doDispatch(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1067 
    TestDispatcherServlet(DispatcherServlet).doService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 963   
    TestDispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 1006  
    TestDispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 909   
    TestDispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 681   
    TestDispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 883  
    TestDispatcherServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 72 
    TestDispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 764   
    MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 167 
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 59 
    AuthTokenFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119  
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 67   
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 327 
    FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterInvocation) line: 115    
    FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 81   
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 121 
    ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 115 
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 126    
    SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 81 
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 105  
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 149    
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 63 
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 59 
    AuthTokenFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119  
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    LogoutFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 103   
    LogoutFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 89    
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 91  
    CorsFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119   
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 90    
    HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 75  
    HeaderWriterFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119   
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 110   
    SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 80    
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 55    
    WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119 
    FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 336 
    FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 211   
    FilterChainProxy.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 183   
    DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1(DelegatingFilterProxy).invokeDelegate(Filter, ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 358   
    DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean$1(DelegatingFilterProxy).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 271 
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    OrderedRequestContextFilter(RequestContextFilter).doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 100  
    OrderedRequestContextFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119  
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    OrderedFormContentFilter(FormContentFilter).doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 93 
    OrderedFormContentFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119 
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter(HiddenHttpMethodFilter).doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 94   
    OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119    
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter).doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 201    
    OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 119   
    MockFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 134 
    MockMvc.perform(RequestBuilder) line: 199   
    AssignmentControllerTest.testCreateAssignment() line: 83    
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 77  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 568  
    ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(Method, Object, Object...) line: 688   
    MethodInvocation<T>.proceed() line: 60  
    InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation<T>.proceed() line: 131  
    TimeoutExtension.intercept(Invocation<T>, ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method>, ExtensionContext, TimeoutDuration, TimeoutProvider) line: 149    
    TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(Invocation<T>, ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method>, ExtensionContext, TimeoutProvider) line: 140   
    TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(Invocation<Void>, ReflectiveInvocationContext<Method>, ExtensionContext) line: 84  
    0x0000000800139ab0.apply(InvocationInterceptor, InvocationInterceptor$Invocation, ReflectiveInvocationContext, ExtensionContext) line: not available    
    ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall<E,T>.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall$VoidMethodInterceptorCall, InvocationInterceptor, InvocationInterceptor$Invocation, ReflectiveInvocationContext, ExtensionContext) line: 115 
    0x0000000800184000.apply(InvocationInterceptor, InvocationInterceptor$Invocation, ReflectiveInvocationContext, ExtensionContext) line: not available    
    ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall, ReflectiveInvocationContext, ExtensionContext, InvocationInterceptor, InvocationInterceptor$Invocation) line: 105    
    0x000000080020efb0.apply(InvocationInterceptor, InvocationInterceptor$Invocation) line: not available   
    InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation<T>.proceed() line: 106 
    InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(Invocation<T>) line: 64  
    InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(Invocation<T>, InterceptorCall<T>, List<InvocationInterceptor>) line: 45  
    InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(Invocation<T>, ExtensionRegistry, InterceptorCall<T>) line: 37    
    ExecutableInvoker.invoke(Invocation<T>, ReflectiveInvocationContext<E>, ExtensionContext, ExtensionRegistry, ReflectiveInterceptorCall<E,T>) line: 104  
    ExecutableInvoker.invoke(Method, Object, ExtensionContext, ExtensionRegistry, ReflectiveInterceptorCall<Method,T>) line: 98
```

Test code for the test that is failing:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProgramController.class)
@WithMockUser
public class ProgramControllerTest extends AbstractTestController 

{

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProgramServices programServices;
    
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    private ProgramDTO programDTO;
    
    private List<ProgramDTO> programList;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
    
        setMockProgramWithDto();
    }
    
    private void setMockProgramWithDto() {
        programDTO = new ProgramDTO(1L, "Java", "Java Description", "Active", Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()), Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        programList = new ArrayList<ProgramDTO>();
    }
    
    @DisplayName("Test for Creating a Program")
    @Test
    @WithMockAdmin
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testCreateProgram() {

//        given(programServices.createAndSaveProgram(ArgumentMatchers.any(ProgramDTO.class)))
//                .willAnswer((i) -\> i.getArgument(0));
Mockito.when(programServices.createAndSaveProgram(Mockito.any(ProgramDTO.class))).thenReturn(programDTO);

        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post("/programs/saveprogram")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(programDTO)));
    
        resultActions.andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$.programId", equalTo(programDTO.getProgramId()), Long.class))
                .andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$.programName", equalTo(programDTO.getProgramName())));
    }
```

Controller code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@Api(tags="Program Controller", description="Program CRUD Operations")
public class ProgramController

{
@Autowired
private ProgramServices programServices;

    @PostMapping("/saveprogram")//,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")  
    //@ResponseBody
    @RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    @ApiOperation("Create Program")
    private ResponseEntity<?> createAndSaveProgram(@Valid @RequestBody ProgramDTO newProgram)throws  DuplicateResourceFoundException
    {  
        System.out.println("in create program");
    ProgramDTO savedProgramedDTO = programServices.createAndSaveProgram(newProgram); 

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedProgramedDTO);  
    } 

}
```

AbstractTestController code:

```
@Import(TestWebSecurityConfig.class)
public class AbstractTestController {

    @MockBean
    private UserServices userService;
}

@TestConfiguration    // This Configuration is only for Test
public class TestWebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityConfig webSecurityConfig() {
        return new WebSecurityConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthEntryPointJwt authEntryPointJwt() {
        return new AuthEntryPointJwt();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtUtils jwtUtils() {
        return new JwtUtils();
    }

}
```

There are a few previous posts with similar title, but the answers didn't help me. I am  looking forward for some suggestions to solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: 1. You dont need MockitoExtension. 2. What is AbstractTestController? 3. Please post entire stack trace of failed test, not one stopped at a breakpoint.

Comment: Thank you for response. AbstractTestController is a class with TestWebSecurityConfig imported. I will post the code for it. I will post full stack trace too.

Comment: @Lesiak , I have update the requested information in the post. Let me know if any other info is needed. Thanks.